# How do I do a synchronous ReactDOM.render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

For my app, I need to render some children, and then measure the resulting div. In pseudo code, it would look something like this:

```
function getDims(child) {
    var testEl = document.getElementById('test-el');
    ReactDOM.render(child, testEl);
    var dims = testEl.getBoundingClientRect();
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(testEl);
    return dims;
}
```

Unfortunately, according to the documentation ReactDOM.render may in the future become asynchronous. Is there a future-proof option to force synchronous rendering so the above function will work?

Comment: I imagine you could use [react-dom-server](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html) with `renderToStaticMarkup` or `renderToString` and insert that string into the DOM afterwards. Of course it's a bit sad to serialize into a string without the need for it. But if `async` isn't an option it may just work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a callback to `ReactDOM.render(ReactElm, DOMNode, callback)`. The `callback` will be executed once the `ReactElm` gets loaded into the `DOMNode`.

Hope this helps!

```
function getDims(child) {
    var testEl = document.getElementById('test-el');
    ReactDOM.render(child, testEl, function(){
       var dims = testEl.getBoundingClientRect();
       ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(testEl);
       return dims;
    }); 
}
```

Usage example:

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  render(){ return <h1>Hello</h1>}
}
  
  ReactDOM.render(<App/>,
    document.getElementById('app'),
    () => console.log('Component Mounted'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Hi I'm specifically asking how to do this synchronously in future - there are times when I would rather block rendering while I calculate some dimensions than get a FOBUC

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that! If React is giving a async way of rendering stuff and you want to make it synchronous, it not possible. It's more like, 'how to make ajax synchronous?'. And I don't think there is another way to render component into the DOM without using `ReactDOM.render`. Instead, you can use the callback or React may return a `promise` using which you can built a `async await` (ES 7 feature)

Comment: ajax can be synchronous. call it jax or sjax or whatever, it is ajax and synchronous.

Comment: Downvoted because this is not an answer. The answer is either non-existent, or "you can't."

Comment: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18: https://react.dev/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide#updates-to-client-rendering-apis

Answer (score 1):

In React 18+, we can use [`renderToString`](https://react.dev/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide#updates-to-client-rendering-apis):

```
    const view = renderToString(<div id="text-div-id">{text}</div>);

    const outerEl = document.getElementById('outer-div-id') as HTMLDivElement;
    outerEl.innerHTML = view;

    const textEl = document.getElementById('text-div-id') as HTMLDivElement;
    const bounding = textEl.getBoundingClientRect();
```